# Why was this question marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, scope

This question isn't duplicate anymore. Why do people criticize beginners?
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82672/what-is-the-length-of-a-photon

Comment: Please be clearer in your questions. As it stands,that one is very unclear if not a dupe.

Comment: The real duplicate of your question is "how is wavelength actually related to space distance":


 http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74316/how-is-wavelength-actually-related-to-space-distance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're not criticizing anyone here. Please don't misunderstand.

Closing is reversible. In case you've asked for something else and we've misunderstood you, the question can be reopened. But, it's you who should make it clear. Express it to us, by editing your question to add, how your question isn't a duplicate, what exactly you were trying to ask, and more specifically, think whether it's meaningful in its current form, etc. Once you've edited, the votes would also attain *reversibility*. Had your question transformed into a good one, people will revoke their downvotes (for sure). No one's angry...

You've asked, *"Hey, what's the length of a photon?"*. And, we said, "Hmm... We've already got a more generalized question on the size of quantum particles, where yours might be a proper subset".
Then, you say, *"No, it's not..!!!"*

More simply, telling us "NO, NO, NO" isn't gonna work it out. Instead, you should explain why it's not a duplicate in its current form... ;-)

Comment: someone said a good enough photon has 90-60-90.means my question is foolish

Comment: @anupam if you feel that a comment is unwarranted, then definitely flag it.  But as CrazyBuddy said, it is on you to make the question crystal clear as to what you are asking.